# SharePoint CAML Query AND/OR operators

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml

I would appreciate any help on getting my CAML query to work.
I have the following list:

```
| ID | Department | Status |
```

I am trying to get the query to return `list items where ID=1, Department=Audit, and Status= "Stopped" OR "In Progress".`

Can anyone please help?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='ID' />
            <Value Type='Counter'>1</Value>
         </Eq>
         <And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Department' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>Audit</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Or>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='Status' />
                  <Value Type='Choice'>In Progress</Value>
               </Eq>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='Status' />
                  <Value Type='Choice'>Not Started</Value>
               </Eq>
            </Or>
         </And>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

> Note: it is assumed that Department is a `Choice` field

---

I would recommend you to utilize the tool that will help you build your CAML Queries, for example [U2U Caml Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. Very handy tool